How to get rid of the original variable for swift Macro?
So I'm making a PeerMacro that I'm almost got the base case done. However, the only thing that I want to do is get rid of the original variable (AKA static let loans: String) and replace the entire thing with the closure. Anyone know how to do this? FYI: I'm somewhat new to Macros.
    public static func expansion(
        of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax,
        providingPeersOf declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntaxProtocol,
        in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntax] {
        guard let variableSyntax = declaration.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self),
              let variableSyntaxAttributes = variableSyntax.attributes.first?.as(AttributeSyntax.self),
              let labelListSyntax = variableSyntaxAttributes.arguments?.as(LabeledExprListSyntax.self)
        else {
            throw MacroExpansionError.message(
                "Could not read the variable syntax"
            )
        }

        // Makes sure the variable is properly formatted
        guard let staticModifierListSyntax = variableSyntax.modifiers.first?.as(DeclModifierSyntax.self),
              let bindingsListSyntax = variableSyntax.bindings.first?.as(PatternBindingSyntax.self),
              let identifierSyntax = bindingsListSyntax.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)
        else {
            throw MacroExpansionError.message(
                "Variable is not properly formatted"
            )
        }
        let staticKeyWord = staticModifierListSyntax.name.text
        let letKeyword = variableSyntax.bindingSpecifier.text
        let variableName = identifierSyntax.identifier.text

        guard staticKeyWord == "static",
              letKeyword == "let",
              !variableName.isEmpty
        else {
            throw MacroExpansionError.message(
                "Variable is not properly formatted"
            )
        }

        // Makes sure that the URL exists
        guard let urlStringLabelSyntax = labelListSyntax.first?.as(LabeledExprSyntax.self),
              let urlStringLiteralSyntax = urlStringLabelSyntax.expression.trimmed.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self),
              let urlStringSegmentSyntax = urlStringLiteralSyntax.segments.first?.as(StringSegmentSyntax.self)
        else  {
            throw MacroExpansionError.message(
                "First argument for URL is missing or not the right type"
            )
        }
        let urlString = urlStringSegmentSyntax.content.text

        return [
            DeclSyntax(stringLiteral:
            """
                \(staticKeyWord) \(letKeyword) \(variableName): String = {
                    return String(format: "\(urlString)")
                }()
            """
            )
        ]
    }

    func testMacro() throws {
        #if canImport(AFEndpointMacros)
        assertMacroExpansion(
            """
            struct Endpoints {
                @AFEndpoint("/v2/test/")
                static let test: String
            }
            """,
            expandedSource: 
            """
            struct Endpoints {
                static let test: String = {
                    return String(format: "/v2/test/")
                }()
            }
            """,
            macros: testMacros
        )
        #else
        throw XCTSkip("macros are only supported when running tests for the host platform")
        #endif
    }

from expected output (-):
 struct Endpoints {
+    static let test: String
+
     static let test: String = {
–        return String(format: "/v2/test/")
–    }()
+                    return String(format: "/v2/test/")
+        }()
 }

Actual expanded source:
struct Endpoints {
    static let test: String

    static let test: String = {
                    return String(format: "/v2/test/")
        }()
}


As I said in your previous question, macros cannot do this. You need to redesign this. Since the macro just generates a value for the let constant, how about changing it to an accessor macro that adds a getter? The getter's body will then be return String(format: "/v2/test/"), or whatever else the macro would generate.

Peer macros introduce a peer declaration: "The macro expansion can introduce "peer" declarations that sit alongside the given declaration.". Perhaps one of the other macro types is more suitable. Though in general, Macros aim to add code or wrap existing code, but never remove it, so that it's easier for readers to make sense of them.

Another approach would be to use a freestanding expression macro to generate the closure. The use-site would look like static let test = #Endpoint(...). This might be more suitable, given your previous question. But I cannot comment further without knowing more about exactly what this macro is designed to do.

Thanks I'll look into this a bit more as I learn more about the macros.. I want to look at accessor first but I think the freestanding would definitely work.

@Sweeper Thanks for the guidance I was able to get what I wanted done with a accessor macro.
